# Do I need to configure a development device to test Apple Push Notification and Update of my Pass

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios7, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am creating a passbook server in ruby on rails.
No problem to generate,download and remove a valide pkpass on my Iphone.

However, when I use this project https://github.com/nomad/houston to implement apple push notification I can't get the notification my web app sent.

Anymore, when I use this project https://github.com/mattt/passbook_rails_example/blob/master/app/controllers/passbook/passes_controller.rb to implement update of my pass, this last is not modified after an update.

Apparently, my device needs to maintain a stable connection between my device and APNS. So my question is: Do I have to create a development provisioning profile to register my device? Or is this supposed to work with any device?

Comment: u need a dev profile. while creating profile u need to mention that this profile needs push notification access

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it when I created all certificates related to passbook in the provisioning portal.

Comment: For Passbook, you need to send an empty APNS payload to the production APNS server and connect using your Pass Type ID certificate.  You cannot use a Dev profile or the sandbox APNS for Passbook push updates.

Comment: For now, I just want to use in development mode (without ssl certificates). My goal is to make a complete passbook application(development mode) and then integrate ssl in order to hit the production APNS server.

Comment: You can set your development device to accept a http WebService, but you still need a Pass Type ID cert to open a secure socket to the production APNS server.  There is absolutely no way to send a Passbook update push without securely connecting to the production APNS.  Your Passbook WebService implementation and the APNS are independent of each other.

Comment: I generated a pem file using my p12 certificate. In my update function, I define the path to this pem certificate for the Houston project (The one that handles notifications to APNS).

Comment: So if I understand well your answer, I can't use gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com (development environment) to test notifications. I have to use gateway.push.apple.com in order to see if it works?

Comment: Correct - and the p12 needs to be your Pass Type ID, not a push certificate.

Comment: It's now working for the update. I had to regenerate the pass and to send him in bytes. I followed your advice for the APNS and still no notification on my phone :(. Do you know how can I debug this? For now, I use the console log of Xcode to see what 's happening on my device (no trace of an incoming request once the notification was send by my server)

Answer (score 0):

To use non-https, you have to put your device into developer mode using Xcode and then in settings on the device there is a new setting to allow non-secure passbook URLs.